# How to find the parent from the collected element?

Tags: jquery

i have a variable stored 3 divs.

Each div has a tille element. while clicking the title element, I need to make accordion function, is it possible..?

I tried like this, but not working:

```
var sectors = $('#parent').find('div > div') //it returs the length 3

var title = $('#parent').find('h3') // as well it returns 3.

function//

$(title).click(function(){
    $(sectors).slideToggle();//it's working... i am hiding all
   $(sectors,':first').slideToggle();//it's not working... i need to show the sibling elment
})
```

is there any way to fix this? instead of traversing dom, i am just doing it using variables.

Comment: What does the markup look like?

Comment: Please provide some markup, and also please correct your code, as this wouldn't run;

Answer (score 0):

This <strike>$(sectors,':first').slideToggle();//it's not working..</strike>

should be: <strike>$(':first', sectors).slideToggle();</strike>

Edit:
<strike>sectors.hide();</strike>
<strike>$(this).next("div").show();</strike>

Edit 2:
There were a lot of problems with your code, i've corrected them and updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLdKw/2/) with a working code. However, i would advice you to put all the html, script and css here as well.

Comment: But this is always sling the first element.. i need in whichever title user click, it's sibling need to show, rest need to close..